# Can you pick and choose what gets inherited in a sub-class in Swift?

Tags: swift, inheritance, initialization, subclassing

I have a base class (Spaceship) that has some variables and an initializer. 
I also have a subclass (UFO) that only needs one of the variables of the superclass.
When I try and create a basic UFO object, I get: "missing argument for parameter 'weapon' in call var c = UFO()"
I realize that error message is asking for a weapon parameter, but how do I (and is it even possible?) to create a basic UFO object that doesn't need a weapon parameter?

Have spent hours tinkering with "override", "init" and "super" commands. I've read a lot of the articles here on SO and other sites, but have not seen any examples similar to my situation. Again, I'm assuming that what I want to do is possible to begin with.

```
class Spaceship {

    var isUFO = false  
    var weapon:String 

     init(weapon:String) {      
         self.weapon = weapon
     }

    func printSomething() {
     print("Test")
    }
}

class UFO: Spaceship {
}


var a = Spaceship(weapon:"Laser")
a.printSomething() //OUTPUT: Test

var b = UFO(weapon:"")  
          //This runs, but I don't want to have to fill in parameters
b.printSomething()    //OUTPUT: Test

var c = UFO()       //Ultimately this is what I want to do
c.printSomething()  
       //OUTPUT: missing argument for parameter 'weapon' in call var c =    UFO()
```

Comment: Use composition (put the properties that not all subclasses should have in protocols and cherry-pick which subclass should conform to which protocol) instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is mark `weapon` as `optional String`. Also, in `init(weapon:)` use ***default value*** of `weapon` as `nil`, i.e

```
class Spaceship {
    var isUFO = false
    var weapon: String? //here...

    init(weapon: String? = nil) { //here...
        self.weapon = weapon
    }

    func printSomething() {
        print("Test")
    }
}
```

Now, you can simply create the object of `class UFO` both with and without `weapon`, i.e.

```
var a = Spaceship(weapon:"Laser")
var b = UFO(weapon:"Another Weapon")
var c = UFO()
```

Comment: Ah! That worked! Have never seen the String? = nil part used before. Is that called anything special? Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: That's just providing the default values of the parameters in the method. After that you can have multiple versions of the methods based on the parameters.

Comment: Don't know. Maybe someone thinks this is just a work-around and inheritence shouldn't be used in this way (similar to my answer).

Comment: @AndreasOetjen There can be multiple solutions to a problem. Its just depends on the context and the perspective.

Answer (score 1):

First, when using inheritence, you'll have to think about an "is a" relationship: An UFO *is a* spaceship. So when each spaceship has a weapon, and an UFO is a spaceship, then every UFO also has to have a weapon.

What you *could* do is make your weapon an optional, but I think this is somehow a mis-usage. Also, re-think your `isUFO` property:

- A spaceship should not make assumptions about special subclasses
- You could use the `is` operator to check the dynamic type of a `Spacehip`

If you don't want this inheritence behaviour, you might better think about something else, like protocols, where you only specify certain behaviour but no memory layout.